# Will Hydra protocol implementation require changes in consensus protocol (Ouroboros)?

Tags: hydra

As I understand Hydra protocol has two main components:

1. [Hydra Head protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/299.pdf)
2. [Hydra Interhead protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1188.pdf)

Does any of these components require changes to current consensus protocol? If not, how will it be implemented? My guess is as a smart contract + some network communication protocol (possibly p2p).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Hydra is a layer-two solution which works "on top of" Cardano. A hydra-node which implements the Hydra Head protocol will run alongside the cardano-node and provide an isomorphic state channel which has the same transaction format and ledger rules as Cardano, but with a much simpler consensus. The fact that not the whole network needs to agree to reach consensus in a single Hydra Head, but only the participants of a particular Head, makes this faster & cheaper than to process transactions on the mainchain.

Comment: Small addition: while it may not require changes in the current consensus protocol, Hydra makes heavy use of Plutus smart validators and it may require changes in the Plutus core built-ins to cope with fancy crypto and fancy structures used to manage the Hydra head on-chain state.

Comment: Also, as I understand it, Hydra subnetworks will be capable of their own consensus/trust models, as well as their own ledger models.